# How to store name of uploaded file and use it in the back end

Tags: angularjs

Trying to figure this issue out, googled a bit but couldn't find a working solution so hopefully someone has a better idea than me. I've got the ability to upload a file and would like to use the name of said file in a message which is produced from the backend.

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <input name="testfile" id="testfile" type=file
           filereadastext="targetEntity.testfile">
</div>
```

I tried `$scope.filename = $scope.file.name` but it didn't work.

Any help?

Comment: What `Content-Type` does the code use when posting the file to the backend?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Retrieve the name of the file I've uploaded for a logging statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60645282/retrieve-the-name-of-the-file-ive-uploaded-for-a-logging-statement)

Answer (score -1):

You should get a `name` from a `File` object which is passed to a callback function. `<input type="file" (change)="pushFiles($event)" />`
Find some examples here
https://github.com/shystruk/file-upload-component/blob/master/angular%205.0/app/services/file-upload.service.ts#L20

Comment: The `(change)` is Angular 2+ syntax. The question is about AngularJS. They are different frameworks.

Comment: Check this file for AngularJS. https://github.com/shystruk/file-upload-component/blob/master/angular%201.6/components/file-upload/file-upload.directive.js

Comment: Here is workable code for that :) https://github.com/shystruk/file-upload-component/tree/master/angular%201.6

Answer (score -1):

Try this in your JSP/View file :

```
<input ng-class="applyClass" type="file" onchange="yourFun()" required
       file-Model="selectedUploadFile" name="file">
```

And in your Controller read / log file name as below:

```
console.log($scope.selectedUploadFile);
```

This should work as expected